# Updating multiple columns depending on 1 CASE-condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a program that needs to synchronize it's frequently changing values (in temporary memory) with a database. The critical key (not primary!) in that table is the column ***id***. My program changes the ***id*** but keeps the old ***id*** in memory, too.

Now, I would like to update several specified columns for multiple records/rows in one single statement. Furthermore, it should be reasonably fast for 5 up to 10 of such statements in 1 second with 4 GB RAM and ~ 50 MBit/s connection that is not only used for these sql-calls.

**My sql-specifications**

- Server: 127.0.0.1 via
- TCP/IP
- Software: MySQL
- Software version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Protocol version: 10
- Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

I tried to use brackets...

```
UPDATE someTable
SET (id, name) = CASE id 
WHEN 1 THEN (111, "Dr. Frankenstein") 
WHEN 2 THEN (222, "the Monster") 
WHEN 3 THEN (333, "Mr. X") 
ELSE (id, name) END
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

...which simply results in the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(id, name) = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN (111, "Dr. Frankenstein") WHEN 2 THEN (222,' at line 2
```

Know I wonder: Is there a way to do it in just one statement with the current syntax? Would it be feasable that way or should I just split it into multiple statement which is ugly in terms of the program that makes the sql-calls.

Answers and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `case` statement only returns one value:

```
UPDATE someTable
    SET id = (CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 111 WHEN 2 THEN 222 WHEN 3 THEN 333 ELSE id END),
        name = (CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'Dr. Frankenstein'
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'the Monster'
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Mr. X'
                        ELSE name
                END)
    WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

For performance, be sure you an an index on `id`.  This will help with finding the records to update.  Do note that changing the `id` value requires updating the index, which can be a bit longer than a normal `update`.  However, expecting 5-10 transactions a second is reasonable.

Comment: It's be pretty odd not to have `id` indexed; any self-respecting schema should already have set it as the primary key.

Comment: I made that choice because there would be a very special id-conflict otherwise. Of course, I could change the whole design of the program and database to remediate this. For The moment, I like it quick and dirty.

Comment: This solution does not work at this stage. At least my MySQL-Database disliked the semicolon after setting ***id***. Exchaning it with a comma does the job. As in Sashi Kants answer the order is of great importance. Setting/Updating all columns before the ***id***-column seems to be a must.

Comment: @FlorianR.Klein . . . I don't know why there was a semicolon there.  A semicolon should only be at the end of the statement.  I mistyped what should have been a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
UPDATE someTable
SET id = CASE 
id 
WHEN 1 THEN 111
WHEN 2 THEN 222
WHEN 3 THEN 333
ELSE id END
,
 name = CASE 
id 
WHEN 1 THEN "Dr. Frankenstein" 
WHEN 2 THEN "the Monster" 
WHEN 3 THEN "Mr. X" 
ELSE name END

WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: This does not work because of the two redundant ***SET*** right before the name-assignment. There is problem in the order, too: I must switch the setting of ***id*** and ***name*** because the ***id*** is set immediately and the ***CASE*** of the ***name*** comes after the changes (find no ids because they have been altered).

Comment: Sorry, have changed that
Kindly check